# sed - Variables as row positions

Tags: sed, variable

I tried to use variables (**row positions**) as parameters to 'cut' a file, but I got an error in the sed command.

Here is my code:

```
START=$(grep -n "pattern1" $FILE | cut -f1 | sed 's/:.*$//g')
END=$(grep -n "pattern2" $FILE | cut -f1 | sed 's/:.*$//g')
sed -n '${START},${END}p' $FILE > temp; # error here
# sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `S'
```

But it works when I use the numbers:

```
sed -n '28,63p' $FILE > temp;
```

It seems to be some escape that I need to apply, but I couldn't solve it. Any suggestion?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change to double quote, as discussed, but if the file has more than one times the pattern, the original script broken too.
The solution above works well, just print every row between the start/end patterns.
This oneliner print just the first occurrence:

```bsh
    sed -n '/pattern1/{:loop;p;/pattern2/q;N;s/.*\n//;b loop};' "$file"
```

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your code is that you are expecting the shell to expand your `START` and `END` variables within a single-quoted string. The shell would never do this, and it is one of the main differences between single and double-quoted strings.

Instead, use a double-quoted string for your `sed` expression.

However, you also seem to be expecting your two `grep` pipelines to return precisely one line number each, in which case I don't see a reason for them as you could do this form `sed` directly.  Commands in `sed` take addresses in the form of line numbers, regular expressions, or combinations of these if the command takes more than a single address.

```bsh
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/ p' "$FILE" >temp
```

or

```bsh
sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/ !d' "$FILE" >temp
```

---

You should probably not keep your `grep` pipelines, but this is to add that you could shorten them to something returning the line number from `sed` directly.

```bsh
start=$( sed -n '/pattern1/ { =; q; }' )
```

The above would give you the line number of the first line matching the pattern `pattern1`. It is the `=` command that outputs the current line number.

Comment: It's great :)! I remarked.